# How to differentiate popover by id or class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I am facing one issue , I am having two popovers and inside this I am passing html

Here is my code

```
<button class="count" data-toggle="popover">+click me</button>
<div  class="popover_content_wrapper" style="display: none">
  <p>Rahul</p>
</div>

<button class="count" data-toggle="popover">+click me</button>
<div  class="popover_content_wrapper" style="display: none">
  <p>Dravid</p>
</div>
```

In my Js Part

```
  $(function() {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({ html : true,
        content: function() {
            return $('.popover_content_wrapper').html();
        }
    })
  })
```

But if I click the first button it's working fine and showing "Rahul " in pop up

but if I click the second button it also showing "Rahul",  but I want it to need to show "Dravid"

Comment: try : `return  $(this).find('.popover_content_wrapper').html();`

Comment: Please respect the order of posting. The accepted answer is an implementation of the comment above. My solution is much shorter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `$(this).next()` as it is immediate next `div` to clicked `button`.

```js
$(function(event) {
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({ html : true,
        content: function() {
            return $(this).next('.popover_content_wrapper').html();
            // or $(this).next().html()
        }
    })
  })
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<button class="count" data-toggle="popover">+click me</button>
        <div  class="popover_content_wrapper" style="display: none">
             <p>Rahul</p>
         </div>

<button class="count" data-toggle="popover">+click me</button>
        <div  class="popover_content_wrapper" style="display: none">
             <p>Dravid</p>
         </div>
```

Comment: @mplungjan i didn't copied your code . I was just writing inside js `code snippet` while adding `bootstrap dependencies` . It seems like you and me almost posted same time.

Comment: I did not accuse you of copying (I see your dependencies are different than mine)

Answer (score 2):

Navigate from $(this)

```js
$(function() {
  $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
    html: true,
    content: function() {
      return $(this).next().text(); // or .html();
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<button class="count" data-toggle="popover">+click me</button>
<div class="popover_content_wrapper" style="display: none">
  <p>Rahul</p>
</div>

<button class="count" data-toggle="popover">+click me</button>
<div class="popover_content_wrapper" style="display: none">
  <p>Dravid</p>
</div>
```